# CUDA not working on Blender 2.9 - GTX 750Ti - Win10 64b

Tags: rendering

As per title. I've seen there are other people with this problem.
It looks like everything should be OK, even downloaded the latest Nvidia drivers, those not for games.

[image]

This is what happens when I try to render:

[image]

And then, quit to desktop.

Comment: Blender will not use some older GPUs fully. Newer GPUs are fully used by Blender.  Please Consider searching for [compute capability] from NVidia.  You can also see websites that rate GPUs ... Passmark?

Comment: It's true that my gfx board is getting old, but the GTX 750 Ti falls into the CUDA enabled, version 5, which should work.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: In my experience with many GTX 780, those cards can fail randomly. Sometimes all there is to do is turn the computer off and on again. The same scene then renders correctly.

Comment: Tried several times, it just doesn't work.